# Is there an iOS library to help me detect higher-level accelerometer gestures?

Tags: iphone, mobile, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

For example, let's say I want to detect if the user made a circle gesture so I can trigger something in my game. Is there a library that would allow me to just listen for some sort of "circleDectected" event?

If there isn't, would anyone find value in something like this if I developed it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist (as far as I know).  You would have to do it manually, which shouldn't be too hard, but it could potentially be time consuming.  I think it'll be fantastic if somebody made a library to do it.

Comment: I hope to answer your prayers in a near future!

Answer (score -2):

Unreal Engine seems to have support for it - Infinity Blade uses a lot of gestures for casting spells.

Comment: If I follow you logic : my iPhone has transit schedule and uses UIKit. Therefor, UIKit has transit schedule. It makes not sense. It's not because Infinity Blade has it that Unreal Engine has it.

Comment: That Harry Potter spell app does it.  Does that mean it uses Unreal Engine?